# Humanism and Its Aspirations (Humanist Manifesto III): Individual or collective "life fulfillment?"

Tags: humanism

Referring to [Humanism and Its Aspirations (Humanist Manifesto III)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism_and_Its_Aspirations), the fourth premise is:

> Life’s fulfillment emerges from individual participation in the
>   service of humane ideals.

...what does "Life's fulfillment" mean here? Is this "life" as in "my individual life" or "life" as in "the life of humans in general?"

Comment: I would say it is the individual hooking himself on to a project which is bigger than his strictly selfish interests, so I would say: the life of humans in general as a way of giving meaning to the individual life. Abraham Maslow spoke of this as "self-actualization". https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.psychologytoday.com/blog/theory-and-psychopathology/201308/the-theory-self-actualization%3famp

Comment: I am making a guess. I have no special knowledge of how this Manifesto was developed, what sources they used and so on. But I make an educated guess that Humanistic psychology is a part of this entire movement. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanistic_psychology